# When should SelectFont be Called?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

I was fixing an issue to do with scaling and the solution was that we had to call `SelectFont` afer `DrawText`.

If `SelectFont` is called before `DrawText` the font isn't scaled correctly.

I cant see how that would make a difference, is there any reason?

Comment: Asking us to comment on code that you won't show us is not productive. Make an MCVE.

Comment: You are using a font that doesn't scale well, or your assumptions about scaling are wrong. See [Scaling Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266.aspx#scaling_text) for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

`SelectFont` essentially selects a font in the Device Context you pass in. If you call `DrawText` before selecting a font, then a default font (System) will be used and not the font you want to select.

This means that the font you are using isn't scaling well as the results seem better with the default system font.